# Using map with enum e class members

Tags: c++, dictionary

Ok, I have the following class:

```
class Shader {
public:
    ...
private:
    GLuint _vertexShader;
    GLuint _fragmentShader;
}
```

Is it possible to create a mapping between enums(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER) and the variables I declared in the class?
The reson for this is that I want to generalize a method that I am creating for this class.

```
switch ( shaderType )
        {
        case GL_VERTEX_SHADER:
                _vertexShader = glCreateShader( shaderType );
                glShaderSource( _vertexShader, 1, &shaderCode, 0 );
                glCompileShader( _vertexShader );
                glGetShaderiv( _vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled );
                break;

        case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER:
                _fragmentShader = glCreateShader( shaderType );
                glShaderSource( _fragmentShader, 1, &shaderCode, 0 );
                glCompileShader( _fragmentShader );
                glGetShaderiv( _fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled );
                break;
        }
```

As you can see from this code, I have to do a switch to do basically the same code, but with just the variable changing. So it would be a lot nicer if I could instead of using switch, mapping the GLenum with the respective variable.

Comment: could creating two subclasses be an acceptable option?

Comment: one class for each type of shader?

Comment: Just an idea to change the design since you need to create two kind of shaders

Comment: `std::map<GLenum, GLuint*>`?

Comment: yes, I think pointer would work. But thinking about design, would be better doing a map or doing subclasses? I am a beginner with OOP, since I will be using this class often, I want to have something nice

Comment: @lhahn If an object will only ever be one kind of shader (that is, you don't plan on being able to change the type of a shader after it is constructed) then subclasses are appropriate.

Comment: Can I edit the question with an idea of a class? (I don't know because it doesn't have much to do with the original question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct answer:
you could make a mapping from an enum to a pointer to data member:

```
std::map<GLenum, GLuint Shader::*> mapper; 
mapper[GL_VERTEX_SHADER  ] = &Shader::_vertexShader;
mapper[GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER] = &Shader::_fragmentShader;
```

or, if the enum id's have values 0 and 1:

```
std::vector<GLuint Shader::*> mapper(2); 
mapper[GL_VERTEX_SHADER  ] = &Shader::_vertexShader;
mapper[GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER] = &Shader::_fragmentShader;
```

Then you just factor out the common code by parameterization of type GLuint&.

```
template <typename SC, typename Bool>
void CreateShader(GLuint& shader, GLenum shaderType, SC& shaderCode, Bool& isCompiled)
{
     shader = glCreateShader( shaderType );
     glShaderSource( shader, 1, &shaderCode, 0 );
     glCompileShader( shader );
     glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled );
}
```

And then:

```
CreateShader(this->*mapper[shaderType], shaderType, shaderCode, isCompiled);
```

But for this example I would just use a switch and not define, initialize and use the (global?) mapper object:

```
switch ( shaderType )
{
    case GL_VERTEX_SHADER:
            CreateShader(_vertexShader, shaderType, shaderCode, isCompiled);
            break;
    case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER:
            CreateShader(_fragmentShader, shaderType, shaderCode, isCompiled);
            break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I didn't really think of references, I guess maybe I don't even need a map

Comment: You can combine the above in: CreateShader(this->*mapper[shaderType], shaderType, shaderCode);